# React error: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': The node before which the new node is to be inserted is not a child of this node

Tags: javascript, reactjs, simplebar

I am trying to map the response I get from an api call. I want to render a div in this map. This is what my code looks like:

```
<div data-simplebar className="img-scroll">
    {this.state.imageSearchResults.items.map((item, ind) => {
        return <div className="image-square" style={{backgroundImage:`url(${this.state.imageSearchResults.items[0].link})`}}></div>
    })}
</div>
```

I am getting an error saying

```
Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': The node before which the new node is to be inserted is not a child of this node.
```

What is wrong with this? I have done mapping in same way in the past and never got such an error.

Comment: I had the same problem, but in my case it was because the parent DIV had other element which was not a result of the `map` function. I've created an inner DIV and included the `map` inside it, and then the error was gone.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone stumbles upon this problem while a page is being translated in Google Chrome, it's likely it has something to do with this:

https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/11538

It's an old issue that's yet to be solved by the Chrome team:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=872770

Comment: Good Catch. Kinda same issue and your answered helped

Comment: See also this answer from 2020: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65110044/327074

Answer (score 1):

Please add a reasonable `key` prop to the children.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at this `<div data-simplebar className="img-scroll">` in your question, it looks like you are using the ['simplebar' plugin](https://github.com/Grsmto/simplebar), which changes the DOM tree and breaks React.

Try to use the package for React ['simplebar-react'](https://github.com/Grsmto/simplebar/tree/master/packages/simplebar-react) instead, it works correctly.

[React example](https://github.com/Grsmto/simplebar/blob/master/examples/react/src/App.js):

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import SimpleBar from 'simplebar-react';

import 'simplebar/dist/simplebar.min.css';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to React</h1>
        </header>
        <p className="App-intro">
          To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <SimpleBar style={{ height: '300px' }}>
          {[...Array(50)].map((x, i) =>
            <p key={i} className="odd">Some content</p>
          )}
        </SimpleBar>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrapping up the translatable text within `<p> or <span>` sorted out issue for me