# Uncaught NotFoundError: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node':

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a `div` where inside another three `div`s are appending as follows. The state values are setting by looping the result from an api from `componentWillReceiveProps()`. But I'm facing an issue with an error

> `Uncaught NotFoundError: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': The node before which the new node is to be inserted is not a child of this node`

and if the api result is null gets

> `Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.`

How can I fix this?

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    var sub1 = [], sub2 = [], sub3 = [];
    if(result) {
        result.sub1.map((item, index) => {
            sub1.push(
                <div>
                    <p>{item.name}</p>
                </div>
            )
        })
        result.sub2.map((item, index) => {
            sub2.push(
                <div>
                    <p>{item.name}</p>
                </div>
            )
        })
        result.sub3.map((item, index) => {
            sub3.push(
                <div>
                    <p>{item.name}</p>
                </div>
            )
        })

        this.setState({ subDiv1:sub1, subDiv2:sub2, subDiv3:sub3 })
    }
}

render() {
    return(
        <div className="row top_bar">
            <div className="search left col-xs-5 col-sm-4 col-md-5 col-lg-6">
                <form>
                    <input type="text" id="search_box" name="search_box" placeholder="Search" onKeyUp={this.keyUpFn} />
                </form>
                <div className="div1">
                    { this.state.subDiv1 }
                    { this.state.subDiv2 }
                    { this.state.subDiv3 }
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="top_right col-xs-7 col-sm-8 col-md-7 col-lg-6">
                <div className="top_outer">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a full runnable example please? This message sounds like a bug.

Comment: This is somewhat a small portion of my project. To create this as a runnable example is little difficult now. Please don't feel bad

Comment: I think something like `insertbefore` should be used somewhere. I don't know where to use it. Do you have any idea?

Comment: My best guess is you have some code that messes with the DOM produced by React, and when React later tries to update it, it can't find the nodes. But it's hard to say without seeing your project. In general, the code you showed is quite strange. You're not really supposed to use React like this. Instead, rendering should be done in the render method.

Comment: Is this a wrong method to loop and set state from `componentWillReceiveProps` and use state value inside the render method ?

Comment: You should almost never need `componentWillReceiveProps` in your code. Yes, it's probably wrong, but I can't say what's the right way because I don't know what you're trying to do. Typically you shouldn't need to put JSX outside the render method.

Comment: Also, what is `result`?

Comment: This is for a search box and the search api result will be of three types and each type separately looping and appending them to a div.

Comment: Why aren't you doing this in `render`?

Comment: As you suggested I tried the same thing inside the render and got the same error.

Comment: I can't help without a reproducing example.

Comment: I think its because of appending the three `div` parallel to the main div inside render. But I couldn't find a solution for this and I'm stuck with this. Will be helpful if you could help me

Comment: Can you help me if I give you the api result?

Comment: Not really, the problem is in the code.

Comment: Please check the updated render method in the question. Can you find any issues now?

Comment: No, as I said earlier this error might mean something is messing with the DOM. It might be in another component or another library. Like if you use jQuery or something similar.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173033/discussion-between-hareesh-s-nair-and-dan-abramov).

Answer (score 44):

Sometimes it happens when users use Google Translate, it mutates text nodes, and React breaks on the next render.
More info and how to fix it:
https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/11538#issuecomment-390386520

You can also add the next properties to the HTML tag to disable Google Translate and fix this problem:

`<html class="notranslate" translate="no">`

Comment: Is translating via Google Translate in Chrome then fully disabled then or just not automatically translated?

Comment: @CodingYourLife, it will fully disable Google Translate on the page.

Comment: This just saved my day!!! :+1:

Answer (score 22):

I believe this is failing because you are rendering outside of the render method.  I also had this problem and it was because I had code like the following in my render method:

```
<div id="myContent">
  {this.getMyContentFromAChildClass()}
</div>
```

And then elsewhere in the class, I was using a 3rd party library, SimpleBar, to add a scrollbar to the div using JQuery like so:

```
const myContentElement = $("#myContent")[0];
if (!this.scrollbar && myContentElement) {
  this.scrollbar = new SimpleBar(myContentElement, {autoHide: false});
}
```

SimpleBar adds it's own divs in the mix, and when React tried to render the `{this.getMyContentFromAChildClass()` it was confused where to add it, and I got the above error message.

The fix was to not modify the parent div directly:

```
<div id="myContent">
  <div id="addingThisExtraDivIsTheFix">  <-- Add This
    {this.getMyContentFromAChildClass()}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're a legend for this answer, been trying to fix this issue for hours now but added an extra container inside the parent and my code works now:)

Comment: Awesome answer: thanks a lot for doing this! 
Would be extra ideal if we could really understand _it was confused where to add it_ by looking at the source/mechanism?

Answer (score 2):

The solutions above did not work for me.

What worked was adding a `key` to the parent, based on the changing values. In React, a changed `key` is an indication to re-render the component, which is what OP wants in this case.

Change the parent `div` with `className='div1'` to the following:

```
<div className="div1" key={JSON.stringify(nextProps)}>
```

Comment: I spent many minutes on this error and this fixed it for me. Adding a key to the parent object did the magic.

Answer (score 1):

whoever comes here and uses MaterialUI and you are using `<LoadingButton>`, that is likely where the crash happens.
Simply wrap the children in a span to fix it.

```
<LoadingButton><span>Text</span></LoadingButton>
```

Comment: why would the LoadingButton causing such issue?

Comment: @YaserAZ see for full answer https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/27853

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. In my case, I have also installed DeepL and TransOver on my Chrome. My solution was removing DeepL and TransOver extensions as well as disbling Google Translate then it became working. FYI, Only disabling DeepL and TransOver extensions may works as well.